# Can't update Chrome - requires installation of untrusted packages

Tags: updates, google-chrome

On a very recently installed 16.04 with the latest official chrome deb file from google installed, update manager says "requires installation of untrusted packages" when the latest chrome update is selected. All other updates work just fine, so it is kind of specific to Chrome.

There's nothing about Google/Chrome in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, so my question is twofold:

1. how does update manager know it has to update chrome?
2. what would be the cleanest way to remediate?

There's many answers about this error messages, but it seems none touches on this exact case and most suggest many arbitrary commands which are obviously an overkill for this exact scenario.

Any reminder of how these things work would be highly appreciated along the answer.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` from terminal? Please add terminal output to the question.

Comment: Is there a Chrome entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` ? If so, please include the complete contents in  the question